# nmap script with credentials

Tags: nmap

I'm using **Nmap** for penetration testing for a while, and I need to know:

Assuming I obtained user credentials, is there any script that I can use, for searching what resources this user is able to access?
 e.g What places he's able to connect (**RDP**).

I used this script:**smb-enum-shares.nse** to reveal the shared folders he can access, but this can be done easily with other programs.

Comment: And for the RDP, from what I've seen, there's no way to map the **credentials' available RDP targets** except, examining a specific target manually, checking that port number 3389 is open and then trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nmap is designed for service enumeration, and as a bonus, it has scripts that can dig a little deeper, but that's not really what it is intended for. If you have a user's creds, you need to switch to other tools to dive into that user's scope and reach.

Comment: **Do You have any idea for such tools?**

Answer (score 3):

For the broadest coverage with the fewest arguments, use your credentials as input into Nmap's credential brute-forcing scripts. Any of the scripts that use the [`unpwdb` library](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/unpwdb.html) will read usernames and passwords from a common source, which you can specify on the command-line:

```
nmap --script brute --script-args "userdb=userfile,passdb=passfile"
```

If the `userfile` contains the username and the `passfile` contains the password, then the brute-forcing will just use the one combination and then end.

Use caution in selecting scripts, though; not all of the [`brute`-category](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/categories/brute.html) scripts use `unpwdb` library, so some of them may perform bruteforcing with other lists of usernames and passwords: [Here's a list of them.](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Anmap.org%2Fnsedoc%2Fscripts%2F+inurl%3Abrute+-"passdb")

Comment: I like your solution,
 the only downside of the "**Brute**" scripts is that it does not appeal to **RDP** (Remote Desktop Protocol)

Comment: In addition, do you know what should be the file extention for those DB's?  
I created 2 .lst files containing the user name: domain\user and the password . e.g.`nmap --script brute --script-args userdb=/home/myname/nmap_user.lst,passdb=/home/myname/nmap_pass.lst,unpwdb.userlimit=2,unpwdb.passlimit=2 192.168.10.1` **but no result was given** I'm wondering if it's because you have to give a specific file extension for the `userdb` and `passdb` **OR** because they should be on a different location>??

Comment: @yuda41 no particular file extension is needed. But some versions had a bug where absolute paths could not be used. Try using `-d` to get debug output, and use relative paths.